# How to use data header as variable name in R

Tags: r, variables, header

I am trying to run a stepwise regression in `R` with  600 odd variables contained as the column name from the header of a .csv file.

How do i use the column name as variables in a regression equation?

I am very new to this and my limited understanding it that i can save the column as a list and use it for running a glm  eg

`model.1 <- glm(x~ paste(list), family= poisson, link = logit).`

Any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you don't have to but use `~.` instead as in: `lm(mpg~., data=mtcars)`

Comment: When you read the file into R with option `header=TRUE`, the column names are the variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have read your data in correctly (e.g. with `header=TRUE` as specified in the comments above), you should end up with a 600+-column data frame (1 column for the `x` response, and a column for each predictor variable): I will call this `mydata` for now. In that case as @TylerRinker suggests you could just include all the predictors: `glm(x~.,data=mydata,family=poisson)` (the logit link is the default link; if you want to specify it explicitly you can say `glm(x~.,data=mydata,family=poisson(link="logit"))`. You could then use `step`, or `stepAIC` from the MASS package.

However, I have to add that unless you know what you're doing, stepwise regression on 600 variables is a ***really, really, really BAD*** idea from a statistical point of view (Google something like "stepwise regression problems" or "stepwise regression Harrell"). I would strongly encourage you to take a look at something like the `glmnet` package, which takes a more sensible approach to modeling with lots of predictors.

Comment: thanks @Tyler, @Patrick! @ Ben ! thanks for additional suggestions, as you rightly pointed out that stepwise wont to a good idea. I have explored glmnet package and it looks very promising for my work.